# Query data not passing from response into variable

Tags: javascript

Dumb newbie question so please assume that I have much to learn.

My code below is for a function which retrieves the average pay for a job from an API database. The **variable "soc"** is the job name which is submitted to the API.

There are 2 possible scenarios :

1. The job is submitted, the remote database has sufficient data to provide average pay and this is sent in the response. **This scenario works fine for me and the pay is always displayed in my html**. Both alert messages appear.
2. The job is submitted but the remote database has insufficient data to provide average pay. In this scenario the API should respond as follows:

   ***Response Body**
   {
    "error": "Sample size for this data is too small to be reliable. Relax your   filters, or try a coarse query."
   }

   **Response Code**
   404*

However, when I submit an "insufficient data" job **the pay for the last successful job query is displayed** instead in my html. Strangely **both alert messages fail to appear**.

So what I need I a method to detect the response error and respond by putting "Not available" into my pay variable. How do I detect an error which does not generate an alert ?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

```
$.get("http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
{ soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"},
 function(datani) {

alert(datani);

var nipay = maxBy("year", datani.series).estpay ;  //load data into variable

alert(nipay);

$("#graph-box1").html("<p><b>NI:</b> " + nipay +  " GBP/week </p>") //   display the result

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> your code should look some thing like this

```
    $.get(
      "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
   {soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"})
  .done( function(datani) {
        alert(datani);
        var nipay = maxBy("year", datani.series).estpay ; 
        alert(nipay);
        $("#graph-box1").html("<p><b>NI:</b> " + nipay +  " GBP/week </p>") 
     })

   .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* handle the error */ });
```

Comment: Eureka ! Many thanks @Nauman Ahmad. After 3 days of pulling my hair out it works !

Comment: @Eureka You are welcome please mark the question as answer if it had help you :)

Answer (score 2):

The success callback only fires if the request was successful. Getting a 404 error in the response is one way to indicate that the request wasn't successful.

The `get` shorthand method doesn't accept an error callback.

You can use the full `ajax` function instead.

```
$.ajax(
    "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
    {
        data: { soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"},
        success: function(data) { /* etc */ },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* etc */ }
    }
);
```

Alternatively, `get` (and `ajax` for that matter) return a jqXHR object which implements the promise interface.

```
$.get(
    "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
    { soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"}
)
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { /* etc */ })
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* etc */ });
```

Comment: Thanks @Quentin I will look into this and give it a go.